# Can't get response in hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I'm new to javascript and I have an issue with setting hook var to the response of request.
Here is request:

```
export const getAdminUsers = async (offset = 10, page = 0) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`${_apiBase}/api/v1/admin/user/?page=${page}&offset=${offset}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        return await res.json()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Here is useState and useEffect hook:

```
    const [adminUsers, setAdminUsers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
             getAdminUsers().then(res=>setAdminUsers(res));

    }, [])
```

Didn't find anything helpful to solve this.

Edit: When I use console.log() instead of setAdminUsers it works fine.

Edit: I added where I use adminUsers. Hope it helps.

```
{validateSearch(adminUsers).map((i, index) => (
<SearchUser
    user = {i}
    index={index}
    page = {page}
    key = {index}
/>
))}
```

Here is validateSearch(). It works fine, I checked it before.

```
    const validateSearch = (users) => {
        let validatedUsers = [];
        if (inputValue === "") {
            validatedUsers = users;
        } else {
            
            for (let i = 0; users.length > i; i++) {
                if (!users[i].full_name) { users[i].full_name = "" }
                if (users[i].full_name.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())) {
                    validatedUsers.push(adminUsers[i])
                }
            }
        }
        return validatedUsers;
    }
```

Page is just a component parameter that tells which component it is(I use this component with similar list), that has the same problem. You can ignore page var.

Here is an example of how I use adminUsers elements inside SearchUser component:

```
<div className="item-name">
    {user.full_name ? user.full_name : "No name"}
</div>
```

Comment: If you can log it and get the correct result, it should work. How are you using `adminUsers`?

Comment: I use .map() and then use data from adminUser in component

Comment: Could you post this part of the code, or at least a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Are you getting a valid response? you should be checking the response status or code

Comment: Status is ok and code is 200. When I use console.log(), it works fine.

Comment: And what does validateSearch do can you post that. Also you shouldnt be using index as a key prop. And where are you getting the "page" variable from?

Comment: I edited question with some additional data. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm it's pretty hard to tell. What is happening exactly, is it crashing the UI or just showing blank, are there errors? In your validate function you are pushing an element from adminUsers and you are using input value from upper scope too these could be stale and that might cause problems. Your also updating an element in the user array and then returning a new array I imagine that is not what you want. Soz it's very hard to tell from these snippits if you create a sandandcodebox I'll be happy to check it for you

Comment: Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-pasteur-bts33?file=/src/App.js I don't know why, but request doesn't work in sandbox

Comment: The link works in the sandbox the fetch is failing

Comment: Yeah, but it works outside sandbox, i don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: Thats the cors policy on the server - you said that is working so rather than mess with that, if you provide what the response json example we can just add that in

Comment: I replaced response json with an example

Comment: I added a dummy response and filled the gaps and your code on the sandbox is working fine https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-varahamihira-wrdgb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! I ' ll try this.

Comment: Ive also added some better error handling in (Its not great) - I know its tedious but adding error handling from the start will really help you identify your issues quickly

Comment: Thanks for advice! So, I have to put my res.json() in resolve of promise instead of that object?

Comment: The function with the promise constructor is just a dummy function to dummy your api response - that object doesnt need parsing as it was created in js. Your original getAdminUsers needs to parse the json response so thats why the .json method is in that function and not the dummy. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I added in the functionality I think you are trying to create :D